# Redirect a user back to the page they where on before submitting the form

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like the user to redirect back to a page they where on before submitting the contact form, after they have landed on the *thank you* page on my WordPress site.

When a user submits this form, this form redirects to a *thank you* page.

On this *thank you* page, I would like to be redirected back to the page they where on before they submitted the *contact* page.

1. Main contact form
2. Thank you page
3. Redirect the user back to the page before the contact page

If I create a variable and store the refer from the *contact us* page:

```
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Then carry this over to the *thank you* page

```
if ($referer == '/contact-us');
```

When I am on the *thank you* page, I want to be redirected after 4 seconds back to the page I was on, before I submitted the form on my *contact* page.

Comment: use `header("Refresh: 4; url=http://www.example.com/contact-us");` ?

Comment: Thanks FDL, redirecting back to the contact page is not an issue as I have doen this. I would like to redirect the user back to a page they where on before they arrived on the contact page, I am sure this is done using a refer but I can't get his to work.

Answer (score 1):

Use either [header()](http://php.net/header) or a [meta refresh](http://www.quickiwiki.com/en/Meta_refresh) on the thank you page.

```
header("refresh:5;url=" . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>">
```

I would also advise checking on the SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] before using this method as well as its a little flaky.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, using something like

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
```

is unreliable since it is sent by the client browser.

Why don't you post the page URL when the destination is the main contact page and pass it along to the 'Thank You' page?

EDIT: Besides, if the main contact page is accessed through a direct link, do you want the 'Thank You' page to redirect to the main contact page or the external page the user accessed before coming to your site?